# Condition of equivalence of 2 equations?

Tags: soft-question

Let $U=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Z}^3$ and $a(U),b(U),c(U),d(U),e(U),f(U),g,h$ be integers.

Now consider the system of equations:
$$x[a(U)]+y[b(U)]+z[c(U)]=g$$
$$x[d(U)]+y[e(U)]+z[f(U)]=h$$

What conditions must this system satisfy so that both equations are equivalent?

My guess is : $$a(U)e(U)-b(U)d(U)=0$$
$$b(U)f(U)-e(U)c(U)=0$$
$$a(U)f(U)-d(U)c(U)=0$$

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are.
If $a=d,b=e,c=f$ but $g\ne h$, your three determinants are all zero but the two equations are not equivalent.

Comment: So we must $g=h$.

Comment: Well, in my counterexample, yes. But in general, it can be $g\ne h$. What you are looking for is the concept of _linear dependence,_ which can be defined in $Z$-modules as well as in vector spaces.